# Override dask scheduler_port

Tags: dask

I've tried several ports without success: 8787 is indeed busy serving rstudio. I could redirect rstudio, but shouldn't the following work?

```
from distributed import Client, LocalCluster
cluster = LocalCluster( scheduler_port = 8785 , n_workers = 2 )
```

Error:

```
/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/bokeh/core.py:56: UserWarning: 
Port 8787 is already in use. 
Perhaps you already have a cluster running?
Hosting the diagnostics dashboard on a random port instead.
  warnings.warn('\n' + msg)
tornado.application - ERROR - Multiple exceptions in yield list
```

...

```
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/forkserver.py in connect_to_new_process(self, fds)
     64             raise ValueError('too many fds')
     65         with socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX) as client:
---> 66             client.connect(self._forkserver_address)
     67             parent_r, child_w = os.pipe()
     68             child_r, parent_w = os.pipe()

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to override the `diagnostics_port` instead:

https://github.com/dask/distributed/blob/2ec428ae5652f7d068baeb18223fb8a04ab8804e/distributed/deploy/local.py#L45-L49